# Create DateTime object from various strings

Tags: c#, string, datetime, datetime-parsing

I have a string that is in the format of a date. I want to convert it to a `DateTime` object. However I am not certain of the format of the string.

Are there any methods that I can use so that it will work on following inputs?

```
"12/31/2015", "31/12/2015", "2015-12-31"
```

Comment: Have you tried: `var date = DateTime.Parse(yourString);`

Comment: @Barnstokkr based on the OP's culture that would fail for either the first or second date.

Comment: Would `05/04/2014` be April or May?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DateTime.TryParseExact` method has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes your formats as a string array.

```
string s = "";
DateTime dt;
var array = new[] {"MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, array, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //
}
```

I used [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) because [`/` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means, if you use [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it doesn't have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx), your parsing will fail *even* if your string and format exactly matches.

### But remember

This way is okey for your examples.

But string like `01/02/2015` is a problem because this method can't know that this is `1 February 2015` or `2 January 2015`. In such a case, this method parse your string with **first** successfully matched format.

> However I am not certain of the format of the string.

If you want to full successfully parse for your all examples, you *have to* know their exact formats.

Answer (score 4):

You can use TryParseExact with a list of expected formats.

```
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
DateTime outputDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(inputText, formats, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list of allowed cultures:

```
        var list = new List<string> {"12/31/2015", "31/12/2015", "2015-12-31"};
        var allowedCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            foreach (CultureInfo culture in allowedCultures)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(s, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", culture.DisplayName, dt.ToShortDateString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DateTime.Parse`. try this code:

```
// Define cultures to be used to parse dates.
      CultureInfo[] cultures = {CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), 
                                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"), 
                                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")};
      // Define string representations of a date to be parsed. 
      string[] dateStrings = {"01/10/2009 7:34 PM", 
                              "10.01.2009 19:34", 
                              "10-1-2009 19:34" };
      // Parse dates using each culture. 
      foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
      {
         DateTime dateValue;
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversions using {0} culture.", 
                           culture.Name);
         foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
         {
            try {
               dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture);
               Console.WriteLine("   Converted '{0}' to {1}.",
                                 dateString, dateValue.ToString("f", culture));
            }
            catch (FormatException) {
               Console.WriteLine("   Unable to convert '{0}' for culture {1}.", 
                                 dateString, culture.Name);
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Parse2_Example)